# What is an example of a pair-wise independent set that isn't 3-wise independent from this sample space S?

Tags: probability, independence

If we flip a fair coin three times, and have a sample space of S = {HHH, HTH, HTT, HHT, TTT, THT, THH, TTH}, what is an example of a set of three events (A, B, and C) that are pair-wise independent, but not 3-wise independent?

After some work, I got this as a final answer:

```
A = {TTT, TTH, THT, HTT}
B = {HHH, THT, HTT, HHT}
C = {THT, HTT, HTH, THH}
```

Is this correct?

```
P(A,B,C) = 1/4
P(A)P(B)P(C) = 1/8
P(A,B) = P(B,C) = P(A,C) = 1/4
P(A)P(B) = P(B)P(C) = P(A)P(C)  = 1/4
```

Comment: @lulu I'm confused by your example.  The OP asked for events that "are pair-wise independent, but not 3-wise independent".  While I agree that in your example, the events are pair-wise independent, it seems to me that the 3 events **are also** 3-wise independent, and therefore do **not** satisfy the OP's request.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @user2661923 I edited the question, sorry to both of you. I typed it incorrectly; he was correct considering the original question.

Comment: I tried another approach and I edited the question again with my new answer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  By the way, I disagree with one of your assertions.  Events A and B can be independent **without** being mutually exclusive (i.e. without being *non-intersecting*).  A simple example is combining one toin coss (e.g. event that toss is Heads) with one roll of one die (e.g. event that die comes up a 5).  The two events are independent, but not mutually exclusive.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the first set A is just an early idea I had, which I stated in the question. The second set (in the code view) is my final answer for a set of three events that are pairwise but not 3-wise independent. I'll try to make this clearer in the question.

Comment: In your latest version with $A = \{TTT, TTH, THT, HTT\}$, 
$B = \{HHH, THT, HTT, HHT\}$ and 
$C = \{THT, HTT, HTH, THH\}$, you have a small error in that $P(A,B,C)=\frac14$ not $\frac18$ but, apart from that, it appears to be a satisfactory example of events which are pair-wise independent, but not mutually independent

Comment: I agree with Henry: chance of A, B, C by themselves are each 4/8.  Given B occurring, chance of A occurring is 2/4.  Similarly, between B and C and between A and C, so the three events are pairwise independent.  The only way that B and C can both occur, is from one of the two events THT, HTT occurring.  If **either** of those two events occur, event A is **guaranteed** to occur.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the answer.